# Как обернуть по два элемента кроме первого и последнего?

Tags: jquery

**Проблема**: хочу обернуть `img` в элементы `li` по два элемента внутри `ul`, кроме первого и последнего. То есть, в моей задаче первый и последний элемент `li` должны содержать один `img`. Остальные — каждый `li` по 2 `img`. Как этого добиться пока не получается.

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <ul class='thumblist'>

    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var someImg = '';
    for(i = 1; i < 17; i++) {

        someImg += '<li><img class="thumb_img" src="thumbs/some/some_2017-' + i + '-' + 'thumb.jpg" /></li>';

    }
        $("ul > li:first-child").addClass('i');
    $('.thumblist').append(someImg);
    $("ul > li:first-child").addClass('i');
    $("ul > li:last-child").addClass('i');
    $('ul > li').not(':first').not(':last').addClass('d');


})
```

Comment: Непонятно какие изображения помещать в `li`. Как соотносятся названия изображений и, допустим, индекс элемента `li`?

Comment: пример http://www.turnjs.com/samples/magazine/#page/2

Comment: а если изображений нечетное количество?

Comment: если нечетное допустим минимум 5  то <li><img /></li> <li><img /></img></li><li><img/></li><li><img/></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если я правильно понял вопрос:

```js
var x = [
  "https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/files/5153fa03c566d71e1c0353a8-icon-256x256.png",
  "https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/files/5337874cc566d76ecc002af9-icon-256x256.png",
  "http://res.cloudinary.com/lightspeed-retail/image/upload/c_pad,h_256,q_100,w_256/epsqrj5gjr0qghfrlmur.jpg",
  "http://www.coreasdistribution.com/wp-content/uploads/Ketel_one_vodka.jpg",
  "https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/files/5153fa03c566d71e1c0353a8-icon-256x256.png",
  "https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/files/5337874cc566d76ecc002af9-icon-256x256.png",
  "http://res.cloudinary.com/lightspeed-retail/image/upload/c_pad,h_256,q_100,w_256/epsqrj5gjr0qghfrlmur.jpg",
  "http://www.coreasdistribution.com/wp-content/uploads/Ketel_one_vodka.jpg",
  "https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/files/5153fa03c566d71e1c0353a8-icon-256x256.png",
  "https://dtgxwmigmg3gc.cloudfront.net/files/5337874cc566d76ecc002af9-icon-256x256.png",
  "http://res.cloudinary.com/lightspeed-retail/image/upload/c_pad,h_256,q_100,w_256/epsqrj5gjr0qghfrlmur.jpg",
  "http://www.coreasdistribution.com/wp-content/uploads/Ketel_one_vodka.jpg"
]


$(document).ready(function() {
  var someImg = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    someImg += '<li>';
    if (i != 0 && i != 9) {
      someImg += '<img class="thumb_img" src="' + x[i + 1] + '" width="100px" height="100px" />';
    }
    someImg += '<img class="thumb_img" src="' + x[i] + '" width="100px" height="100px" />';
    someImg += '</li>';

  }
  $('.thumblist').append(someImg);
  $("ul > li:first-child").addClass('i');
  $("ul > li:last-child").addClass('i');
  $('ul > li').not(':first').not(':last').addClass('d');


})
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.i {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.d {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnails">
  <ul class='thumblist'>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: а как путь путь прописать чтобы все картинки оказались в массиве?

Comment: @radik_zu не понял?

Comment: перебрать картинки  из папки

Comment: то есть то что в примере в переменной x, но уже из папки

Comment: @radik_zu  у вас все картинки лежат "thumbs/some/some_2017-' + i + '-' + 'thumb.jpg" , где i  это порядковый номер. напишите функцию типа for которая перебирает все картинки в папке и заносит в array.push('/ваша картинка/').

Comment: var x = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        var collectImage = new Array;
        collectImage="/thumbs/some/some_2017-' + i + '-' + 'thumb.jpg"
    }
    x.push(collectImage);    попробовал так, чот не вышло, что я не так делаю?

Comment: @radik_zu   https://jsfiddle.net/CRafT/kz8r2ytk/1/

Comment: теперь понял ))

Comment: там  в твоем коде почти  все правильно только нумерация не правильно строится получается так что 1 2-3  3-4  4-5 5-7 7-8 9 каждая предыдущая дублирует  вв

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48231/discussion-between-c-raf-t-and-radik-zu).